# JAX-RS @PathParm which contains multiple slashes (some path)

Tags: java, rest, jax-rs

I need to pass value with multiple slashes as "somePath" @PathParam. Let's say I always need that param in each of endpoint methods.

Is it possible to achieve next endpoints:

```
@Path("/v1/demo/{somePath: .*}")
public class DemoController {

  @GET
  public Response getPath(@PathParam("somePath") String somePath) {
    return Response.status(200).entity(somePath).build(); 
    
    // GET /v1/demo/path/goes/here => should return "path/goes/here" => this works
  }

  @GET
  @Path("/{id}")
  public Response getId(@PathParam("somePath") String somePath, @PathParam("id") int id) {
    // some logic with somePath
    return Response.status(200).entity(id).build();

    // GET /v1/demo/path/goes/here/1 => should return 1 => not working
  }

  @GET
  @Path("/{id}/{name}")
  public Response getName(@PathParam("somePath") String somePath, @PathParam("id") int id, @PathParam("name") String name) {
    // some logic with somePath        
    return Response.status(200).entity(name).build();

    // GET /v1/demo/path/goes/here/1/myName => should return "myName" => not working
  }

}
```

Comment: If your param somePath contains slashes, you need to url encode it on the client side. Like "this%2Fis%2Fmy%2Fparam" instead of "this/is/my/param".

Comment: Yeah that's one of the options, thx. I was thinking if it's possible to do it without any modifications